# Can SyncToy run synchronously for All Folder Pairs?

Tags: synctoy

I'm running two SyncToy folder pairs under the All Folder Pairs option. The first item synchronizes files which are then used by the second folder pair. As such the first folder pair needs to complete before the second starts. I've noticed errors in the second pair because the files are modified subsequent to the start because they are running (I assume) in parallel (asynchronously). Is there anyway to force all folder pairs to run synchronously?